# Gear motor with encoder: minimum drivable step

Tags: motor, encoder

I am fancying this motor http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2271/specs to motorize an X-Y stage. (Alternative High rpm motors with high reduction ratio and high encoder counts/rev are welcome ;)

If possible I want to not use stepper motors, as they are harder to control, and also it might be difficult to achieve speeds about 1k rpm?

What bothers me is the minimum angle/ amount of steps that motor can reliably be driven from rest.

Can anyone provide a good estimate what minimum number of steps I can expect?

Edit:
I have a laser to measure a surface's depth, now I need to translate the surface in a zig-zag pattern. This requires one motor to do one very small step at the end of each line. In this case: <= 1/50 * 360° = 7°, which translates to <70° of the motor shaft, due to the gearbox.

Edit2: angle corrected.

Comment: Assuming a quadrature encoder, 1/4 of the encoder slot increment, adjusted for any gearing between that and the output shaft.  If the sensing technology is analog, possibly a bit better by comparing the actual strength of the two sensor phases.  But in a gear motor, you also need to consider the concept of `backlash` if the direction of loading changes.  Even if the encoder is at the output and not subject to backlash, driving it through the backlash of the gearchain may cause issues with the motor oscillating across the backlash distance.

Comment: Are you sure you can immediately stop the motor after 1 encoder increment (intertia..)?

Comment: A proper control system compensates for modeled load properties. However, backlash in the gearchain may make that impractical.

Comment: You don't drive it at 1k RPM all the way to the target and then crash stop it; you have a PID or similar system that slows it down beforehand.

Comment: Which part of "... **465 counts per revolution** of the gearbox’s output shaft." is confusing? There are other gearbox options that will give you higher resolution if you need it.

Comment: If you want to have precise positional control, I think your comment about stepper motors being harder to control than DC motors is wrong.  With a regular DC motor, you need to make a control system. With stepper motors, you rely on open loop control.

Comment: @user765269 Even without going into the control mechanisms, there must be *some* reason that all the RepRap and other desktop 3D printer designs, various CNC machines, both DIY and commercial, and myriad other systems have designers opting for a stepper motor for precision movement, despite gear motors being "simpler". Food for thought.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - the answer to that is primarily backlash, and secondarily cost/complexity.  Though larger machines almost exclusively use closed loop control of servomotors, either direct drive or through low backlash transmissions such as toothed belts or (for high ratios) harmonic drives.

Comment: Okay, so you're just making your own servo? Remember this too, steppers typically have a resolution of 1.8 degrees per step, and depending on the driver, can go down to 1/32 step(like Pololu's DRV8825), which makes for a resolution of 0.05625 degrees.  To get that same resolution with an encoded  DC motor, you need 6400 counts per revolution, you aren't going to have nearly as good holding torque, backlash will be a major problem...

Comment: @krb686 - you are highly mistaken.  Encoders routinely come in higher resolution than steppers.  And gear motor holding torque greatly exceeds that of steppers, for similar mass & power.  Steppers do have advantages, but not the ones you try to cite.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That was exactly my point: There's reason not to consider a basic geared motor as "simple" for precision positioning.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think you're mistaken. You might be thinking after hooking up a sizeable reduction gearbox.  Look at the values for the motor user76 has posted. 17 oz-in of torque, with gearbox in a 2.3 cubic inch package. This stepper here, http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1208, has a holding torque of 14 oz-in in a 1.4 cubic inch package.  Steppers typically have higher torque at low speeds, and DC motors have higher torque than steppers at higher speeds

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think you're correct actually, it all depends entirely on the gearbox ratio on the motor.  Here's the same motor, but with a 172:1 ratio, giving it 170 oz-in of torque, and 8600 counts per rev.

http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2288/specs

Comment: @kerb686 - the simple fact is that a gearbox can give you both higher resolution and higher torque for a given mass and power draw, than any stepper - steppers are fairly primitive solutions, mostly used in semi-stationary applications where excessive weight and power waste are tolerable.  But that's independent from what some particular random example from a catalog might do.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh-- they use stepper motors and belted systems largely so users can have fun trying to deal with backlash!